# Overflow hidden doesn't work despite having height set

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, overflow

I'm not able to make the overflow to be hidden: http://codepen.io/aiwatko/pen/zKjaLx

```
.loader-overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've browsed the previous threads: I gave the height to the element with the overflow: hidden, I set the other container (my content div) to position: relative, yet when I scroll during the initial animation, I can still see my content that is underneath. I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: 100% is a relative measure. what's this overlay housed WITHIN? You're going 100% of that container's size, not 100% of your browser window.

Comment: @MarcB Is correct. Your `loader-overlay`'s parent is `<body>`, which has no set height. If you want it to be the height of the window, you could try some variation of [vh](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units). Perhaps `height: 100vh;`

Comment: I tested it with chrome on android and it work as expected, which browser give you troubles?

Comment: Percentage heights **require** a height to be set on the parent element. This way they know what **--%** is based on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting your `.loader-overlay` height to be 100%, you are telling it to occupy 100% of its *parent*. Being that the parent in your case is `body`, which does not have a set height, it will not behave as you expect.

What I would suggest is trying out CSS3 Viewport Height (vh). Something like this would set the div to the height of the viewport, which can change dynamically across devices:

```
height: 100vh;
```

This being said, your `content` isn't even in the div with overflow hidden, so it will add to your page's height regardless of what you do with `.loader-overlay`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I have a better understanding of the overflow property!